# Erroneous Azure function invocation with multiple events

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'm currently working on some Azure function which get triggered by EventHub messages formatted in JSON. The EventHub has two partitions and has one consumer group.
Most of the function invocations work correctly, but randomly there are erroneous invocations, which are basically two or more messages packed together.

My Trigger looks like this:

```
public static void Run(
[EventHubTrigger("eh-in", Connection = "eh-in-connection")] EventData dmyEventHubMessage,
[EventHub("eh-out", Connection = "eh-out-connection")] out string outEventHubMessage,
TraceWriter log)
```

I also tried to bind to the message itself via

```
public static void Run(
[EventHubTrigger("eh-in", Connection = "eh-in-connection")] string myEventHubMessage,
[EventHub("eh-out", Connection = "eh-out-connection")] out string outEventHubMessage,
TraceWriter log)
```

but the same errors.
The message just looks like `{myfirstmessage}{mysecondmessage}`.

Do you have any idea why this could happen and how to avoid that?

Comment: Do you mean the body of `dmyEventHubMessage` has concatenated content of two events?

Comment: Yes, both the body of the EventData (`dmyEventHubMessage .GetBytes()`) and the binding to the message `myEventHubMessage ` have the concatenated content of two separate events. For debugging reasons I let StreamAnalytics output every event to a DataLakeStore and there the two messages are actually two separate messages (divided by a newline)

Comment: Ok, that's a mystery. I would suspect sender but hard to say.

Comment: I just implemented a workaround: since I know, that there are no newline in the message I just split the message into the individual messages and write them into a `ICollector<string>`.